# Need a regular expression for alphanumeric with 1 hypen present and space inbetween words

Tags: regex

Can you please provide me with a regular expression that would

- Allow only alphanumeric
- Have definitely only one hyphen in the entire string
- Hyphen or spaces not allowed at the front and back of the string
- no consecutive space or hyphens allowed.
- hypen and one space can be present near each other

Valid - "123-Abc test1","test-   m e","abc slkh-hsds" 
Invalid - "   abc   ", " -hsdj   sdsd  hjds- "

Thanks for helping me out on the same. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Allowing only alphanumeric conflicts with the requirement of a hyphen or space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9] ?)+-( ?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/wWMJ7eRE6L) here.

**EDIT:**

If there can't be a space on *both* sides of the hyphen, then there needs to be a little more:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9] ?)+-(((?<! -) )?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/
                    ^^^^^^^^ ^
```

Alternatively, if negative lookbehind assertions aren't supported (e.g. in JavaScript), then an equivalent regex:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]( (?!- ))?)+-( ?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/
              ^ ^^^^^^^ ^
```

Comment: Hi Thanks it worked :) Yepppeeeee... I was struggling a lot with this one.

Answer (score 3):

1. Only alphanumeric (hyphen and space included, otherwise it'd make no sense):

   ```
   ^[\da-zA-Z -]+$
   ```

   This is the main part that will match the string and makes sure that every character is in the given set. I.e. digits and ASCII letters as well as space and hyphen (the use of which will be restricted in the following parts).
2. Only one hyphen and none at the start or end of the string:

   ```
   (?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)
   ```

   This is a lookahead assertion making sure that the string starts and ends with at least one non-hyphen character. A single hyphen is required in the middle.
3. No space at the start or end or the string:

   ```
   (?=^[^ ].*[^ ]$)
   ```

   Again a lookahead, similar to the one above. They could be combined into one, but it looks much messier and is harder to explain.
4. No consecutive spaces (consecutive hyphens are ruled out already by 2. above):

   ```
   (?!.*  )
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
(?!.*  )(?=^[^ ].*[^ ]$)(?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)^[\da-zA-Z -]+$
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $re='(?!.*  )(?=^[^ ].*[^ ]$)(?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)^[\da-zA-Z -]+$'
PS> "123-Abc test1","test- m e","abc slkh-hsds"," abc ", " -hsdj sdsd hjds- " -match $re
123-Abc test1
test- m e
abc slkh-hsds
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
^(.+-.+)[\da-zA-Z]+[\da-zA-Z ]*[\da-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: This does not ensure a single hyphen, nor does it disallow consecutive spaces as specified by the asker.

Comment: This erroneously rejects the `"test- m e"` string even provided as an example in the question.